# VPAID & VAST standard

Tags: video.js

Does videojs support vpaid in the future?
All major AdCompanies switch to VPAID with VAST 2.0. So it's impossible to run Ads with the standard VAST plugin. 
I'm looking for a solution to implement this. With this feature, videojs would be unbeatable.

Comment: i'm looking for the same feature :/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the videojs-vast plugin from The Onion.
https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin

Comment: As far as I know this plugin only supports VAST and not VPAID.

Comment: Any ideas how to implement VPAID in videojs?

Comment: Soon the same plugin will support VPAID too - https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/pull/50

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working in a plugin for video.js for adding support to VPAID: https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid

demo: http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/

if someone has some issues with the FLASH VPAID please report here: https://github.com/MailOnline/VPAIDFLASHClient

if someone has some issues with the HTML5 VPAID please report here: https://github.com/MailOnline/VPAIDHTML5Client