# Is there a plugin for VPAID support for video.js?

Tags: javascript, video.js, vast

Is there a plugin for VPAID support for video.js?
I tried the video.js [VAST plugin](https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin), but it doesn't support netsonic or Liverail VPAID into the VAST wrapper.

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently working in a plugin for video.js for adding support to VPAID:
https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid

demo:
http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/

if someone has some issues with the FLASH VPAID please report here:
https://github.com/MailOnline/VPAIDFLASHClient

if someone has some issues with the HTML5 VPAID please report here:
https://github.com/MailOnline/VPAIDHTML5Client

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin available, called [videojs-ima](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima), developed by Google. In fact it's just a bridge between video.js and [IMA sdk](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/). 
[Introduction page](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/video_features_and_sdk_versions) states it supports VAST 2, VAST 3, VPAID and VMAP.

**VPAID support**

VPAID support is turned off by default. If you want to enable it just call       `google.ima.settings.setVpaidAllowed(true)` before initializing plugin. Here's an example:

```js
var player = videojs('video-player');
//...
google.ima.settings.setVpaidAllowed(true);
//...
player.ima({
    debug: config['debug'],
    adTagUrl: 'Ad tag here',
    id: 'video-player'
});
```

Definitely check [VPAID support caveats](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/guides/vpaid2js) and more info about VPAID support for IMA HTML5 SDK

## Browser support

Surprisingly IMA HTML5 SDK do not support IE of any versions. Just found out it's [deep in documentation](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/ads#videoFormats)

## Note

IMA heavily relies on google services and logs all the activity of ima and VPAID to google servers. If you don't want to share your data with Google better try something different.

Comment: Also there's a PR waiting to be merged at [videojs-vast-plugin](https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/pull/50) developed by me that has VPAID support of prelinear ads and javascript VPAID sdks. Will update answer when it's merged

Answer (score -1):

Just looking for the same:
[VPAID & VAST standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559486/vpaid-vast-standard)

At this time it seems that there's no solution for this.
Sad, because videojs is so feature complete.

Just stumbled upon another player:
http://www.hdflvplayer.net/

This player seems to support VPAID.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such site today, it is now a commercial product.